# How do I find and use a programatically-created control?

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, tags, controls

I've created a number of buttons on a form based on database entries, and they work just fine. Here's the code for creating them. As you can see I've given them a tag:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count && i < 3; i++)
{
    btnAdd.Text = dataTable.Rows[i]["deviceDescription"].ToString();
    btnAdd.Location = new Point(x, y);
    btnAdd.Tag = i;

    this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
}
```

I use these buttons for visualising a polling system. For example, I want the button to be green when everything is fine, and red when something is wrong.

So the problem I'm running into is referencing the buttons later so that I can change their properties. I've tried stuff like the following:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    // txtOutput1.Text = (result[4] == 0x00 ? "HIGH" : "LOW"); // runs on UI thread
    Button foundButton = (Button)Controls.Find(buttonNumber.ToString(), true)[0];
    if (result[4] == 0x00)
    {
        foundButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        foundButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
});
```

But to no avail... I've tried changing around the syntax of `Controls.Find()` but still have had no luck. Has anyone encountered this problem before or know what to do?

Comment: Why don't you save them in some kind of collection? `myCreatedButtons = new List<Button>()`...

Comment: are you doing this in winforms or asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name your buttons when you create them then you can find them from the this.controls(...

like this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count && i < 3; i++)
    {
        Button btnAdd = new Button();
        btnAdd.Name="btn"+i;

        btnAdd.Text = dataTable.Rows[i]["deviceDescription"].ToString();
        btnAdd.Location = new Point(x, y);
        btnAdd.Tag = i;

        this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
    }
```

then you can find it like this

```
this.Controls["btn1"].Text="New Text";
```

or

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= count && i < 3; i++)
{
//**EDIT**  I added some exception catching here
    if (this.Controls.ContainsKey("btn"+buttonNumber))
        MessageBox.Show("btn"+buttonNumber + " Does not exist");
    else
        this.Controls["btn"+i].Text="I am Button "+i;
}
```

Comment: using this one, the following line produces the error "object reference not set to an instance of an object";

this.Controls["btn" + buttonNumber].BackColor = Color.Red;

Comment: Run it again, when you get the exception check the value of buttonNumber.  it would have to be 0,1,2 to work, if it is anything else, the problem is with buttonNumber.  I tested it and making this call works, so long as the button "btn" + buttonNumber" exists

Comment: ok hang on one more thing then,  how many buttons are on the page. I notice you have int i = 0; i <= count && i ...  which means there is the possiblity that there is 1 or even 0 buttons on the page.  if there is 1 button then buttonNumber should be 0.  Is there 1 button or is there more then 1

Comment: is it perhaps anything to do with that..after drawing the buttons, i'm creating a thread for each button as part of the polling. and it's in one of these threads that i'm trying to access them?

Comment: actually...after running it now, i have noticed that buttons 1 and 3 appear to have not been drawn...although number 2 is...strange. lemme try fixing this..

Comment: Notice in my answer compared to yours.   for (int i = 0; i <= count && i < 3; i++)
    {
        Button btnAdd = new Button();    you are reusing the instance of the button, which means you are morphing it.  You should be starting from scratch evertime with the New Button()

Comment: yeah...for some reason this.Controls.Add(btnAdd) isn't drawing them to the form..

Comment: Trust me I just tested it, look at my first for loop, you need to declare your Button that way, or else you will only get one button, because you only created one button.

Answer (score 2):

Put these buttons in a collection and also set the name of the Control rather than using its tag.

```
var myButtons = new List<Button>();
var btnAdd = new Button();
btnAdd.Text = dataTable.Rows[i]["deviceDescription"].ToString();
btnAdd.Location = new Point(x, y);
btnAdd.Name = i;
myButtons.Add(btnAdd);
```

To find the button use it.

```
Button foundButton = myButtons.Where(s => s.Name == buttonNumber.ToString());
```

Or Simply

```
Button foundButton = myButtons[buttonNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would use a simple Dictionary to store and retrieve the buttons.

declaration:

```
IDictionary<int, Button> kpiButtons = new Dictionary<int, Button>();
```

usage:

```
Button btnFound = kpiButtons[i];
```

Comment: Since the keys are sequential integers starting at 0 it really makes more sense to use a List than a dictionary.  If the keys were not ints (i.e. string keys), or weren't sequential, then a Dictionary would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

@Asif is right, but if you really want to utilize tag you can use next

```
    var button = (from c in Controls.OfType<Button>()
               where (c.Tag is int) && (int)c.Tag == buttonNumber
               select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'd rather create small helper class with number, button reference and logic and keep collection of it on the form.